# ResKit Object Mapping nested objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, restkit

I am attempting to use RestKit to parse some JSON. The app is for tracking competitions, and has a concept of venues, games, and players. A game has a winner and loser (both of class Player) and a venue. The JSON returned by the web service looks like this:

```
[{"id":1,"winner":{"name":"NAME2","id":2,"picture_url":"CK.png"},"loser":{"name":"NAME3","id":3,"picture_url":"NJ.png"},"venue":{"name":"Venue 1","id":2}},
{"id":2,"winner":{"name":"NAME2","id":2,"picture_url":"CK.png"},"loser":{"name":"NAME1","id":1,"picture_url":"NC.png"},"venue":{"name":"Venue 1","id":2}},
{"id":3,"winner":{"name":"NAME2","id":2,"picture_url":"CK.png"},"loser":{"name":"NAME3","id":3,"picture_url":"NJ.png"},"venue":{"name":"Venue 1","id":2}},
{"id":4,"winner":{"name":"NAME2","id":2,"picture_url":"CK.png"},"loser":{"name":"NAME1","id":1,"picture_url":"NC.png"},"venue":{"name":"Venue 1","id":2}}]
```

My object header files look like this:

```
# PTGame.h
@interface PTGame : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *uid;
@property (nonatomic, assign) PTPlayer *winner;
@property (nonatomic, assign) PTPlayer *loser;
@property (nonatomic, assign) PTVenue *venue;
@end

# PTVenue.h
@interface PTVenue : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *uid;
-(CLLocation *)location;
-(CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location;
@end

# PTPlayer.h
@interface PTPlayer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *pictureUrl;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *uid;
@end
```

Finally, my mapping setup looks like:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PTVenue class]];
[venueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name"      : @"name",
                                                   @"id"        : @"uid"}];

RKObjectMapping *playerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PTPlayer class]];
[playerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name"       : @"name",
                                                    @"id"         : @"uid",
                                                    @"picture_url": @"pictureUrl"}];

// Add Object Mapping for PTGame
RKObjectMapping *gameResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PTGame class]];

// Setup Game Object relationships
[gameResponseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"uid"}];
[gameResponseMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"winner" mapping:playerMapping];
[gameResponseMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"loser" mapping:playerMapping];
[gameResponseMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"venue" mapping:venueMapping];

NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

RKResponseDescriptor *gameListResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:gameResponseMapping
                                                                                                method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                           pathPattern:@"/games.json"
                                                                                               keyPath:nil
                                                                                           statusCodes:statusCodes];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:gameListResponseDescriptor];
```

This all looks right to me. No errors are thrown when the result is returned, but later I get an exception when attempting to access a property of the game. A peek into the objects via XCode debugger shows this: [image: XCode Objects]

Something seems to be broken - why do those strings show as "winner" and "venue". Why is the `uid` null? The objects seem different every time I make the request, leading me to believe the memory is not be handled properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the objects correct after mapping? Code looks fine. Suggests it's your memory management elsewhere. Which code ran before the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988185/wain)'s comment led me down the path of looking outside of the mapping code. I looked in the [RestKit Object Mapping docs](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) and noticed all of the attributes were using the `nonatomic` and `copy` properties, rather than `assign`. Additionally, the object references (such as `PTPlayer *winner` were simply `nonatomic`. Changing my code to reflect this fixed the issue.

The resulting header files look like:

```
# PTPlayer.h
@interface PTPlayer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *pictureUrl;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *uid;
@end

# PTVenue.h
@interface PTVenue : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *uid;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat longitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat latitude;
-(CLLocation *)location;
-(CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location;
@end


# PTGame.h
@interface PTGame : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *uid;
@property (nonatomic) PTPlayer *winner;
@property (nonatomic) PTPlayer *loser;
@property (nonatomic) PTVenue *venue;
@end
```